# Change in Vue.js property from event only firing once

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="checkbox" :checked="bool" @change="checked(this)">
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data() {
                return { "bool": true }
            },
            methods: {
                checked(elem) {
                    console.log("Hey!");
                    // Cast to bool
                    this.bool = !!elem.checked;
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

I am planning on implementing some more complex behavior, so I'm not using `v-model`.

When I click the checkbox, the console message logs every time. However, the `bool` property only changes the first time I click, but not on subsequent clicks. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: instead of `this.bool = !!elem.checked` try `this.bool = !elem.checked` you add two `!!` it should be one

Comment: @Joseph Sorry if I was unclear. I am attempting to perform the equivalent of `this.bool = elem.checked`. But `input.checked` is a DOM event object, so I used the `!!` trick to cast it to a `boolean`

Comment: but `input.checked` is already a boolean property in the Dom you don't need to cast it

Comment: `this.bool = elem.checked` causes `app.bool` to go `undefined`. I believe this is because `input.checked` is a `HTMLInputEvent` object which cannot be assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, my mistake. `this` is not the element raising the event, it is the global window object. You can receive the element with `event.target` like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" :checked="bool" @change="checked('Hi!', $event)" id="check">
```

```
this.bool = !!event.target.checked;
```

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/change-in-vue-js-property-from-event-only-firing-once/88105/2

Thanks to @an_parubets for [help discovering this answer!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208584/discussion-between-silver-rampart-and-an-parubets)

Answer (score 1):

When you try to add two `!!` it just removes each other and nothing happens

so you can simply say

```
this.bool = !this.bool
```

it would be like this

```
methods: {
  checked(elem) {
     console.log("Hey!");
     this.bool = !this.bool;
   }
}
```

Comment: That would work in this particular case. However, I would still like to know what is going on because it looks like this behavior is going to cause me problems going forward.

Comment: @SilverRampart when you try to add one `!` it reverses the logical operation but when you add two of them they remove each other

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling the event handler immediately:  `@change="checked(this)"`.
If you need to access the `event` do so:

template:

```
<div id="app">
   <input type="checkbox" :checked="bool" @change="checked('Args', $event)">
</div>
```

method:

```
methods: {
  checked(arg, event) {
    console.log(arg);
    this.bool = !!event.target.checked;
  }
}
```

If you don’t need access to the event - you can simple use like this:

```
<div id="app">
   <input type="checkbox" :checked="bool" @change="bool = !bool">
</div>
```

Comment: Again, this does not solve the problem. Responding to an event once and the not subsequently does not seem like correct behavior. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: What you need clarify?

Comment: Why the expected action is occcuring once, but not subsequently.

Comment: In not possible. Try ```console.log('Hi')``` inside ```toggleChecked```. It fire every time?

Comment: In your question error in the code. ```@change="checked(this)"``` - run once because you immediately run it but not on ```change``` event. When you should run on ```change``` event - try ```@change="checked"```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208584/discussion-between-silver-rampart-and-an-parubets).